# Changing languages in an iOS app

Tags: ios, localization

I have an appllication in created with Xcode, and I want to show in the main view 4 buttons to choose the language of the application (spanish, english, french, german).

When one button is pushed, I want to load the next view (and the rest of the application) in the selected language.

Anyone can guide me please??

Answer (score 0):

Changing localization on the fly is not as simple, because iOS tries to use the current locale for localization, assuming that's the language the user can understand the best. Take look at [this tutorial](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html) to see how to change languages in the app on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here is my solution.

[iOS base internationalization: change the language at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324147/ios-base-internationalization-change-the-language-at-runtime)

I have to say that all of the above is not suitable, you cannot use full power of xcode if you go with a custom macro instead of NSLocalizedString, neither you can trick the StandartDefault - the language wont be set up until you restart the application.